# Alcoolique / alcoolisé

Tags: sens

Sur les caisses de supermarchés, on trouve une affichette du ministère de la santé (ou de l'intérieur ?) qui indique (de mémoire) :

> Il est interdit de vendre des boissons alcooliques aux mineurs.

Ne devrait-elle indiquer plutôt

> boissons alcoolisées ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

J'aurais dit "alcoolisé" aussi mais la [page Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boisson_alcoolis%C3%A9e) donne *Une boisson alcoolisée (ou boisson alcoolique) est...*

Et le Trésor donne en première définition
**Vieilli. [En parlant d'un liquide] Qui contient de l'alcool. *Liqueur alcoolique*.**

- (J. Verne, Les Enfants du capitaine Grant, t. 1, 1868, p. 91.)

> On boit l'eau des torrents dans la montagne, l'eau des ruisseaux dans la plaine, relevée de quelques gouttes de rhum, dont chacun a sa provision contenue dans une corne de bœuf appelée « chiffle ». Il faut avoir soin, d'ailleurs, de ne pas abuser des **boissons alcooliques**, peu favorables dans une région où le système nerveux de l'homme est particulièrement exalté.

Comment: _alcolisé_ est apparu après, en 1620 « rendre (un liquide) alcoolique par production ou addition d'alcool » (J. Beguin, Les Elemens de Chymie dans français moderne, tome 14: **alcolizé**);

Comment: On peut donc dire les deux. Je l'ai également vérifié dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie 9ème édition http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/alcoolis%C3%A9